# When setting picture as wallpaper two entries are shown

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, htc-one-x, htc-sense, htc, wallpaper

I have HTC One X with Android 4.2.2 and Sense 5. When I open a picture in Gallery and try to set it as my wallpaper I see two menu options of "Wallpaper". Below is the screenshot I see:

[image]

Each of the "Wallpaper" menu option opens a different cropping tool. While it does not hinder in my day-to-day work but I would like to know the reason for this. Is this a bug? How can I remove the duplicate "Wallpaper" menu?

Comment: It looks to me like it's arranging the picture differently.  The top one looks like it chops the picture into thirds and spreads them across different pages of the launcher, whereas the bottom one displays the same image on each page.

Comment: @Compro01: Yes it does look like that, but it does not work. Moving between pages does not move the background image irrespective of which cropping tool I use.