# How to switch between scrolling and static wallpapers?

Tags: wallpaper

Two days ago I was a happy scroller, but the all of a sudden its just static, it switched into portrait mode. I've read over the internet that there are some apps to scroll, but I was wondering that, since my phone natively supports scrolling, is there a possible way to switch between scrolling and static?

My cropping square is displayed but the dots are on the center rectangle only, I dont know how to change that.

I'm using an *Inco Flex* if that matters, in case you dont know the brand its ok, its quite unknown.

Answer (score 0):

My scrolling wallpaper went static when I changed the number of desktop screens down to 1. Increase the number of desktop screens for more icon/widget real estate and that scrolling you want.

Oh, make sure your wallpaper is wider than it is tall, too.

Comment: thanks bro! unfortunately enough, i have 5 desktop screens, i can rotate through them, but the wallpaper is still static, my image is way wider than it is tall but when i have to crop it, instead of a square with three little rectangles, i get the three rectangles but only dots in the center one. 
im using android 4.2.2 btw.

Comment: And this happens no matter what wallpaper you select? Have you tried a few?
There's a couple of ways to change the wallpaper, one from the desktop, another from the camera gallery app... tried both? I found this (probably unrelated) issue, may help... [http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58214/when-setting-picture-as-wallpaper-two-entries-are-shown]

Comment: tried both and failed miserably, applied a hard reset and its working again, guess it was a bug... thanks for the help nonethless :D